# Left-align a pandas rolling object

Tags: python, pandas

Using pandas 0.18.1, I'd like to take the rolling average of a one-column dataframe. Since version 0.18.0, this is done with rolling() objects. The default for these rolling objects is to be right-justified. There is a boolean argument you can pass, center=True, to align the rolling object to the center value, but there doesn't seem to be a way to left-align it. Here's an example:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'A': [2,3,6,8,20, 27]})
df
    A
0   2
1   3
2   6
3   8
4  20
5  27
```

The standard method automatically aligns to the right, so there's no value at the first two indecies with a window of size three:

```
 df.rolling(window=3).mean()
           A
0        NaN
1        NaN
2   3.666667
3   5.666667
4  11.333333
5  18.333333
```

We can center-align the operation like this:

```
df.rolling(window=3).mean(center=True)
           A
0        NaN
1   3.666667
2   5.666667
3  11.333333
4  18.333333
5        NaN
```

But what I'm looking for is this:

```
df.rolling(3).mean()
            A
 0   3.666667
 1   5.666667
 2  11.333333
 3  18.333333
 4        NaN
 5        NaN
```

I can accomplish this by doing it with the default right alignment, and then re-indexing it, or by reversing the order of the rows and then doing it "right-aligned" but these are work-arounds for what should be a straight-forward operation.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think you can use [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
a = df.rolling(window=3).mean().shift(-2)
print (a)
           A
0   3.666667
1   5.666667
2  11.333333
3  18.333333
4        NaN
5        NaN
```

Comment: This is a good solution, though I was hoping there was a more direct way to do it. I guess that functionality just isn't in the rolling objects yet.

Comment: I accepted this answer because the desired functionality isn't really in the pandas rolling objects and this provides the most elegant solution. If one wanted to manage this left alignment a little more dynamically, the window size could be set with a variable w, and then the argument in the .shift() method could be w-1.

Comment: Actually, shifting would not handling the case where min_periods=1 and nan's are not present but properly shrunken means.  In that case the only way I see to do it is by reversing the data as mentioned.  Depends on your context.  If min_periods is not set then shifting would be fine.  Pandas should add this ultimately.

Comment: @Alex, its (1-w) actually not (w-1)

Comment: @GregoryMorse why is that? Do you mean the case where min_periods!=1 and nan's are present? Can you elaborate and possibly even better, provide a general purpose answer? Thanks!

Comment: @GregoryMorse if I understand correctly, your point is about the behaviour of the window at the starting edge not being the same as at the ending edge, as seen with `df.rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).mean()`, where the window rolls into the start, but stops abruptly when it reaches the end; returning a df of the same size, instead of including the w-1 extra rows required to roll off the end.

Comment: To see the difference, `df.rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).mean().shift(1-3)` has NaNs at the end, whereas `df.iloc[::-1].rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).mean().iloc[::-1]` does not.

Comment: Thank you @user2561747 that is what I meant, sorry I also got confused by my rather cryptic comment.  Namely when the window shrinks at the end of the data would cause right alignment shrinking window by default.  So you must reverse it, roll it with min periods of 1, then reverse it again, to get a left-aligned window.  There are no NaNs ever with min period of 1 so yes shifting has no application, but to get the window to shrink on the left side is impossible without all this extra processing.

Comment: This solution gets pretty burdensome if the data skips periods. For example, say you have daily stock market data for weekdays but no weekends. If you set your window at, say, "10D" all of the "forward" windows will have data, but then when you try to shift that back, not all dates will exist in the axis, so you get NaNs in the shifted data but no NaNs in the forward-looking data.

Pad/filling the data does not really work either... if you were finding mean price, you don't want to include weekends (which make Fridays triple-weighted). And rolling.mean() does not optionally omit NaNs.

Comment: I just tried this solution and the output values with .shift() were different from the regular df.rolling().sum(). The unaccepted answer below using the FixedForwardWindowIndexer did give me the correct output. I think that answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 8):

Another solution is to simply reverse the DataFrame/Series before applying the right-aligned rolling window, and re-reverse it afterwards. Something like:

```py
In [1]: df["A"][::-1].rolling(3).mean()[::-1]
Out[1]: 
0     3.666667
1     5.666667
2    11.333333
3    18.333333
4          NaN
5          NaN
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

The benefit over `shift` is that it should work with variable sized windows in case of time-based windows.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a [`FixedForwardWindowIndexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer.html) as per the [`.rolling()` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, np.nan, 4]})
>>> df
     B
0  0.0
1  1.0
2  2.0
3  NaN
4  4.0
...
>>> indexer = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=2)
>>> df.rolling(window=indexer, min_periods=1).sum()
     B
0  1.0
1  3.0
2  2.0
3  4.0
4  4.0
```

Comment: So this functionality does exist! But the work around seems to be easier than using the FixedForwardWindow. Still, super interesting to know.

Comment: I don't think there is an equivalent for fixed _time_ length rather than fixed number of rows. For example, if you have data for weekdays and you want your windows at 10 calendar-days.

Comment: The accepted answer using .shift() gave me suspicious results that didn't match the original df.rolling().sum(). This answer gave me the correct output values. Thanks @Ben F!