# Pandas Combining Rolling Features With Group By

Tags: pandas, pivot

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'cust_id': [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                 'period' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6],
                 'volume' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]})
```

I have a customer table with period data for each customer. I want to compute rolling features per customer for 2 different window sizes - 3 and 6.

The output would be:

```
out=pd.DataFrame({'cust_id': [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                  'max_vol_3' : [None, None, 3,4,5,6,None,None,9,10,11,12],
                  'max_vol_6' : [None,None,None,None,None,6,None,None,None,None,None,12]})
```

I guess this is pivoting but the code eludes me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to compute the different windows independently:

```
windows = [3, 6]

r = df.groupby('cust_id')['volume'].rolling
out = df.join(pd.concat({f'max_vol_{x}': r(x).max().droplevel(0)
                         for x in windows}, axis=1))
```

Output:

```
    cust_id  period  volume  max_vol_3  max_vol_6
0         1       1       1        NaN        NaN
1         1       2       2        NaN        NaN
2         1       3       3        3.0        NaN
3         1       4       4        4.0        NaN
4         1       5       5        5.0        NaN
5         1       6       6        6.0        6.0
6         2       1       7        NaN        NaN
7         2       2       8        NaN        NaN
8         2       3       9        9.0        NaN
9         2       4      10       10.0        NaN
10        2       5      11       11.0        NaN
11        2       6      12       12.0       12.0
```

#### using several aggregation functions

```
windows = [3, 6]
functions = ['min', 'max']

r = df.groupby('cust_id')['volume'].rolling
out = df.join(pd.concat({f'{f}_vol_{x}': r(x).agg(f).droplevel(0)
                         for f in functions for x in windows}, axis=1))
```

Output:

```
    cust_id  period  volume  min_vol_3  min_vol_6  max_vol_3  max_vol_6
0         1       1       1        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
1         1       2       2        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
2         1       3       3        1.0        NaN        3.0        NaN
3         1       4       4        2.0        NaN        4.0        NaN
4         1       5       5        3.0        NaN        5.0        NaN
5         1       6       6        4.0        1.0        6.0        6.0
6         2       1       7        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
7         2       2       8        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
8         2       3       9        7.0        NaN        9.0        NaN
9         2       4      10        8.0        NaN       10.0        NaN
10        2       5      11        9.0        NaN       11.0        NaN
11        2       6      12       10.0        7.0       12.0       12.0
```

Comment: One question: The dataframe as I put it is sorted by ID and period. Is this a pre-requisite for this solution to work?

Comment: Sorted by ID, no, as the `groupby` will handle the groups independently. Sorted by period, **yes**, as `rolling` computes the aggregation on the **previous** rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help. One more question: can I add more functions in the for loop? I tried `out.join(pd.concat({f'min_vol_debit1_{x}': r(x).min().droplevel(0), f'max_vol_debit1_{x}': r(x).max().droplevel(0) for x in windows}, axis=1))` but it results in an error

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a way I can set a minimum threshold for each aggregation? Say, in order to compute the minimum for the last 3 periods it needs to have values for at least 2 of the 3?

Comment: Then you need to use a custom aggregation function. That would be a different question ;)

Comment: Thanks! I just posted this extended question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76722538/pandas-rolling-aggregations-that-take-into-account-missing-values

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
def fn(x, windows):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/74359384/10035985
    indexer = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=windows)
    return (
        x.rolling(indexer, min_periods=1)["volume"]
        .max()
        .shift(windows - 1)
    )


df["max_vol_3"] = df.groupby("cust_id").apply(fn, windows=3).values
df["max_vol_6"] = df.groupby("cust_id").apply(fn, windows=6).values
```

it return:

```
df
    cust_id  period  volume  max_vol_3  max_vol_6
0         1       1       1        NaN        NaN
1         1       2       2        NaN        NaN
2         1       3       3        3.0        NaN
3         1       4       4        4.0        NaN
4         1       5       5        5.0        NaN
5         1       6       6        6.0        6.0
6         2       1       7        NaN        NaN
7         2       2       8        NaN        NaN
8         2       3       9        9.0        NaN
9         2       4      10       10.0        NaN
10        2       5      11       11.0        NaN
11        2       6      12       12.0       12.0
```

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately, this function does not take into account if one of the periods is missing. You can try it on the dataset in the linked question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76722538/pandas-rolling-aggregations-that-take-into-account-missing-values